# Understanding connection between containers in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), specifically the part where it says:

> Each container can now look up the service name `web` or `db` and get back the appropriate container's IP address. For example, `web`'s application code could connect to the URL `postgres://db:5432` and start using the Postgres database.

The example says: "postgres://db:5432" so I wonder if the pattern is: "image_name://service_name:container_port"?

Comment: `postgres://` is the _protocol_ - it _so happens_ that it's also the image name in your specific case, but e.g. the official MongoDB _image_ is named `mongo` while the _protocol_ is `mongodb://`. Or you could be using a _different_ image providing Postgres, e.g. (made up) `my-cool/pg-db` but the protocol would still be `postgres://`

Answer (score 0):

In the URI `postgres://db:5432` there are three parts:

- `postgres` — The scheme (indicating the protocol or type of service).
- `db` — The DNS name of the service (this comes from the `docker-compose.yml` file where you have two services named `web` and `db`). This specifies *where* the PostgreSQL service can be found.
- `5432` — The port for the service (the `db` service uses port 5432 internally and this port is mapped to 8001 for external access).